# Impossible to select glossy paper when printing

Tags: printing, canon, pixma

I have a cheap Canon PIXMA Ip2880 printer. I tried to print a pic on glossy paper from Linux, but impossible to select either "*Glossy photo paper*" or "*Photo Paper Plus Glossy II*" in the page setup tab of the print popup. No matter what size print I try (I'm on A4 paper), it won't print and blink 11 times, which means "Paper type and paper size settings are incorrect". If I select "*plain paper*" it works.

Now, are there paper specific sizes that are allowed ? If so, which ones.
And otherwise, how do I print on A4 glossy paper ?!?
Thanks

Comment: Doesn't it work if you just poke glossy A4 in the printer tray?

Comment: Yes, if I select "plain paper", but normally you can increase print quality by selecting the correct type of paper in the driver.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I fixed it by selecting Gutenprint as driver.

Comment: How do you do that? Edit to add more information

Comment: On printer settings. The exact steps vary a lot among distros and desktop environments, yet they should be easy to figure out.

Comment: It is with Gutenprint that I have this problem. With the standard driver, there's simply no glossy option.

Comment: I would ask at: https://sourceforge.net/p/gimp-print/bugs/